# Как в MVC правильно пользоваться моделью и контроллером? (php)

Tags: php, mvc

Хочу написать небольшую админку на phр. Вместе с этим - использую шаблон проектирования MVC. 
Возник такой вопрос: нужно ли создавать во view объект класса controller, для работы через него с model (данными)? 
Например: 
1)Есть БД, в которой находится таблица Users. 
2)В модели я определяю методы для работы с БД (общие методы для запросов, 
типа такого:

```
public function insert($query){
  $insert_str = 'INSERT INTO';
  $isOk = stripos($query, $insert_str);
  if($isOk !== false){
    $this->connect->query($query);
    return "Запись (-и) успешно добавлена (-ы)!";
  }
  else {
    echo "Неправильно записан запрос INSERT!";
  }
}
```

и т.п.); 
3) В контроллере я должен как-то получить данные, которые ввел пользователь во view (а как? если контроллер не знает о view? или я неправильно понял MVC и все таки знает?) -> затем вытащить/внести данные в/из БД и вернуть обратно во view.

При этом, где-то здесь читал, что плохим тоном считается держать объект класса controller во view.

Как правильно поступать в таких случаях?

p.s. Буду рад абсолютно любым замечаниям и советам;)

Comment: Ну во первых зачем вью данные которые ввёл пользователь, данные обрабатываються контроллером(которые ввёл пользователь). В действительности всё просто. Человек запросил url /posts/ запустился контроллер post, контроллер говорить отобразить view post, а вью пост берёт модел post с данными и рендерит её... Вообще вариаций mvc может быть довольно много, но во всех них должно сохраняться схема работы, разделения приложения на логику представления, модель данных, и контроллер.

Comment: @Naumov а вот если пользователь уже находится на странице, и ему нужно получить информацию из БД находясь на этой же странице, нужны же какие-то рычаги, для получения данных из БД? (тут то можно загрузить всю необходимую информацию из БД в переменную и отображать во view) <br> Или даже не так, если пользователю нужно внести какие-то данные в БД, как тогда поступать?

Comment: Ну это может сделать только используя ajax а куда ajax пошлёт запрос? правильно на controller

Comment: @Naumov неужели нету никаких других возможностей, только ajax?

Comment: сокетыы, но механизм тот же. Что бы сохранить, получить данные с сервера всё равно нужно обратиться к нему

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Model-View-Controller**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller) - мультипаттерн в состоящий из трех частей модели, представления и контроллера.

- **Контроллер** подписывается на события от представления и передает полученные вместе с событием данные в модель. Из этого следует что контроллер хранит ссылку на модель и подписан на представление.
- **Модель** содержит всю бизнес логику приложения, по изменению которой посылает события, которые ловит представление.
- **Представление** получив событие забирает из модели нужные ему данные.
  изменившись сообщает это контроллеру послав событие.

`mvc` на сервере означает что либо сервер игровой, либо очень сложного приложения. как правило обычные серверные приложения пишутся на с применением `mvp`.

В привычном понимании приложения на `php` нет `mvc`, есть лишь `mvp`.

[**Model-View-Presenter**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Presenter) - мультипаттерн в состоящий из трех частей модели, представления и презентера.

- **Презентер** хранит ссылки на представление и модель. Презентер берет данные из модели и передает их в представление и если того требует сценарий может действовать по обратному сценарию.
- **Модель**, как правило служит для выборок из БД.
- **Представление** представляется шаблонизатором.

Стоит отдельно заметить, что не имеет значения где будут создаваться элементы той или иной парадигмы и как они будут попадать в нужные места.

Если Вы говорите о том что клиент должен что-то сообщить контроллеру, то это означает что клиент должен сделать запрос на сервер, где его передадут в роутер, который распарсит и приведет переданные данные к пригодному для использования виду и передаст в нужный контроллер.

Comment: Хорошо, общую идею реализации (последний абзац?) я понял, но ведь это намного сложнее, чем просто получить instance контроллера во view и использовать нужные методы там. Неужели в идеале все должно быть именно так, как Вы описали?

Comment: Представлению нельзя хранить ссылку на контроллер. Если Вы подразумеваете под представлением клиентскую часть, то она уж точно не может хранить ссылку на серверный контроллер. Клиент общается с сервером путем запросов.

Comment: Спасибо, и все таки, как мне лучше в данном случае реализовать вставку данных в БД? Если можно так понаглеть - на примере кода?))

Comment: представьте что у Вас нет БД, а есть обычный глобальный массив. Модель получила какие-то данные, возможно что-то с ними сделала и решила положить их в массив. Как она это сделает? Возьмет и положит. А вот теперь представьте что Вы взяли и заменили массив на БД. То есть модель не должна знать что она работает с БД, она должна работать с хранилищем. А хранилище может делать что и как угодно. Вы даже сможете заменить одну БД на другую, но модель это даже не узнает, а ей это и не надо. Модель должна быть только моделью. Используйте сервисные слои везде где сомневаетесь, это самое простое.